# Add Event Listener of Dynamically created web Element

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am writing a chrome extentions whihc determines the clicked elements xpath dynamically. It creates a text area web element with insertAdjacentHTML function (like following) and the clicked elements xpath is placed to it.

```
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',this.html);
    //this.html is string version of text area web element

    document.addEventListener('click', this.getData, true);
```

The above code gets the xpath of the element and places it to the created text area. 
I also want to calculate and show the number of elements that matched with the xpath in the text area(user can edit the text area)
 To do that I am trying to add another eventlistener for the text area element which is like following:

```
 var element= document.getElementById("inspector-text-area")
          element.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            console.log("event fired")
            ...
         });
```

after running the extention, the xpath of the clicked element is placed to created text area web element but when I edit the text area the next added event listener's function is not fired. 
What is wrong I do?
Thanks..

Comment: It should be **"change"** not "onchange" `element.addEventListener('change',function(e){`

Comment: @Eldar I have corrected it, but again it does not work. By the way I also tried event type click or hover. It does not work

Comment: The code you've posted looks correct. 2 things to check: 1. is `inspector-text-area` actually on the page when you call `getElementById("inspector-text-area")`? 2. When do you expect the event to fire? The `change` event only fires when the field value is updated, which usually happens when the field loses focus -- not as the user is typing. If you want to see changes as the user types consider using `keyup` event instead.

Comment: The problem is solved. When I removed the 3tr parementer of the   `document.addEventListener('click', this.getData, true);` it worked. By the way @ChrisCamaratta the type of the event that I want is 'keyup' event. Thank for this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related with the event capturing and event bubbling